# How to print out to a text file folder names within folder names (AppleScript)

Tags: macos, loops, directory, applescript, macos-high-sierra

I have a script that partially works.  I need to print out a list of folder names which is working.  But then I need to go inside of each of those folders into a specific path and then also print out those specific folder names.  Whenever I try and do this my text file comes out blank.  I have separated the text files to try and find the issue and I get the same result no matter what I try.  The first text file works but the second one is always blank.  I would ideally like the second text file o work with that format specified in the script.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
tell application "Finder"
with timeout of 3600 seconds
    set src to (path to me) as string

    set multiPath to (src & "Contents:Resources:Fixed multiSteps")

    set zipFiles to {".zip"}


    set allPlugins to get name of every folder in folder ("" & multiPath & "") whose name extension is not in zipFiles
    set outputFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "pluginNames.txt")
    set typeFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "types.txt")

    set fileReference to open for access file outputFile with write permission

    set filetypeReference to open for access file typeFile with write permission

    try
        repeat with a in allPlugins

            write a & return to fileReference

            set innerPath to (a & "Double Click to Install.app:Contents:Resources")

            set innerFolders to get name of every folder in folder ("" & innerPath & "")

            repeat with b in innerFolders

                write a & " - " & b & return to filetypeReference

            end repeat

        end repeat

    end try

end timeout

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay So I figured it out.

```
tell application "Finder"
with timeout of 3600 seconds
    set src to (path to me) as string

    set multiPath to (src & "Contents:Resources:Fixed multiSteps:")

    set zipFiles to {".zip"}


    set allPlugins to get name of every folder in folder ("" & multiPath & "") whose name extension is not in zipFiles

    set ListFile to ((path to desktop as text) & "List.txt")

    set filetypeReferenceList to open for access file ListFile with write permission

    try
        repeat with a in allPlugins

            set innerPath to (multiPath & a & ":Double Click to Install.app:Contents:Resources")

            set typesForList to get name of every folder in folder ("" & innerPath & "")

            write a & " - " & typesForList & return to filetypeReferenceList

        end repeat

    end try

end timeout

end tell
```